# How to check if an account is associated with an HTS token using the Hashgraph JS SDK

Tags: javascript, hedera-hashgraph

Using the SDK, I was able to obtain a “TokenBalanceMap” using the following code:

```js
const accountBalance = await new AccountBalanceQuery()
.setAccountId(accountId)
.setTokenIds([tokenId])
.execute(client);

const tokenBalance = accountBalance.tokens;
```

But the `tokens` property is marked as `@deprecated` (SDK version is 2.31.0). What’s the recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the mirror nodes is the recommended way to check if an account is currently associated with an HTS token. It’s important to note when you associate with a token it will show you have a 0 balance of that token. Once you receive that token your balance will go up as expected.

Here is how you can check using the mirror nodes:

First, construct a fetch request to get account info by account id.

```
const testnetUrl = 'https://testnet.mirrornode.hedera.com/';
  // fetch the account info
  const accountInfo = await fetch(`${testnetUrl}api/v1/accounts/${accountId}`, {method: "GET"});
```

convert the response to json and grab the associated tokens list from the json

```
const associatedTokensList = accountInfoJson.balance.tokens;
```

Here is a link to the Hedera Mirror Node REST API swagger documentation
https://testnet.mirrornode.hedera.com/api/v1/docs/#/